# How to define a Hash class for custom std::basic_string<> specialization class just like std::string?

Tags: c++, string, hash, c++14

I have a specialization of `std::basic_string`, say, `string_t`, and it the **same** as `std::string` except that the third template argument is my custom allocator.

[std::basic_string<>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Question: How should I define a hash functor class for this specialization using hash functors already provided in C++ standard library?

I know how to define a Hash functor, but I don't know how to utilize existing `std::hash<..>` functors in `std` to define my custom one. I hesitate to write my own hashing operations, knowing it is reinventing the wheel and is unlikely to be better than `std::hash<std::string>`, since the only difference between `string_t` and `std::string` is just the allocator.

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) has some examples but they don't help me much - I don't want to construct a temporary`std::string` object using my `string_t` object's `c_str()` method only to feed the temporary object into `std::hash<std::string>` to get the hash value, because it entails allocating temporary heap memory.

I'm using C++14 and I want to stick to standard library.

Comment: In C++17 you could use `std::hash<std::string_view>`

Comment: @Caleth Indeed, but I don't have C++17 and there are some external constraints. I even wrote my custom string_view.

Comment: You haven't stated for which purpose you will be using this hash. This is the question of crucial importance. If you're going to use it to store your string into standard hashed containers (std::unordered_map, std::unordered_set) then your hash function can be simple since there's no strict requirements here for low collision probability and uniform distribution (although it's better if that's the case). If you're going to use it for cryptography or low collision probability requirements then it becomes more complex.

Comment: @BJovke I am going to use the hash for hashed containers.

Comment: It just bumps into my head that maybe I could static_cast string_t to std::string? Because the only one hinder seems to be compiler's type checking. Didn't get a chance to try, though.

Comment: @Leedehai Well in that case you can cast your string's buffer to, for example, an array of `char32_t` (last elements with padding), XOR all of the values together and feed the result to `std::hash<char32_t>()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Question: How should I define a hash functor class for this specialization using hash functors already provided in C++ standard library?

The short and sad answer is that there is no way to do this. The standard library does not offer hash functions for sequences of integral types.

### Workarounds:

`boost::hash` is superior in every way to `std::hash`. I would suggest you define your `std::hash` specialisation in terms of it.

Furthermore, if you can, specify `boost::hash<>` as the hashing function for all unordered containers. You'll never regret it. `std::hash` is a half-formed library.

```
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>

struct my_alloc ...

using my_string = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, my_alloc>;
std::size_t hash_value(::my_string const& s)
{
            return boost::hash_range(s.begin(), s.end());
}

namespace std {
    template<> struct hash<::my_string> 
    {
        std::size_t operator()(::my_string const& s) const
        {
            return hash_value(s);
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
    auto x = my_string("Hello");

    using Set1 = std::unordered_set<my_string, boost::hash<my_string>>;
    auto set1 = Set1 { x };

    auto h = std::hash<my_string>();
    auto hh = h(x);
    assert(hh == hash_value(x));
    return int(hh);
}
```